# Intranet Application using MVC 4 showing blank screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, iis-7.5, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a sample intranet application using MVC4, .NET 4.5 on Visual Studio 2012, IIS 7.5. When I try to run the app (on IE10/Chrome/FF), it just shows a blank page(No 'Access denied' message) What could be the issue?
Windows authentication is enabled in IIS.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which files do you have in your project when you run the app?

Comment: Well, this issue is not found when i switched to VS 2010! Not able to understand why

Comment: Hi David, commenting out a line <deny users="?" /> solved this problem. Thanks :)